# Create COM-object on server in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, com

I need to create a COM object on server.

In VB you can do this: ([tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/7t9k08y5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

```
xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application", "\\MyServer")
```

But how to do same thing on C#?

I know how to do it locally:

```
 var infsrv = new InfoServ.TInfoServerClass();
```

But don't know how to do it on server..

Comment: What kind of server, where is the software running and do you have office installed on the server.

Comment: @CodingBarfield as far as I know, it's just another PC with win 2003 server. "Excel.Application" - it's a example, in reality it will be a custom COM object

Comment: I'm glad its just an example, it's probably a bad idea to have Excel on a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic so that you can simply use the same method.  This is very much a nicety of .NET, it would be a waste not to use it.  It is however simple to do, just two lines of code:

```
    public static object CreateObject(string progid, string server) {
        var t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progid, server, true);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
```

Well, one line if you push it.  In this specific case you definitely should consider adding a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  You can then simply use the *new* operator, get speedier code because you are not late-binding *and* get IntelliSense.  If you want to stick with late binding then be sure to use the C# version 4 support for the *dynamic* keyword.  Writing late bound code in earlier C# versions is quite painful.

Comment: +1. BTW the OP has now revealed they aren't *really* using Excel, that was just an example. In reality it will apparently be a custom COM object

Comment: Thank you. It kind of works, but return error: `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'InfoServ.TInfoServerClass'. COM components that enter the CLR and do not support IProvideClassInfo or that do not have any interop assembly registered will be wrapped in the __ComObject type. Instances of this type cannot be cast to any other class; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.`

Comment: my code: `InfoServ.TInfoServerClass infsrv = (InfoServ.TInfoServerClass)Activator.CreateInstance(myType);`

Comment: These are the hazards of late binding.  Cast to an interface that's implemented by the COM server, might be named similar to "TInfoServer" but with a leading I or underscore.  Use Object Browser to see it.  The server also needs to support out-of-process activation, it is not automatic.  Ask the vendor or author for help if you are not sure if it does.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` to your C# project and use `CreateObject` directly. This might be the easiest solution if you have an existing codebase that uses a lot of VB.NET specific features:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

...

dynamic xlApp = Interaction.CreateObject("Excel.Application", "MyServer");
```

Note: Since the backslash is a special character in C#, either remove the `\\` from the server name (see above) or escape the string `@"\\MyServer"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08b442cz.aspx) of *Type.GetTypeFromCLSID*.